# Design two possible ways

Tags: java, algorithm

Today I had one interview where I was asked to design two ways.

Situation:

We have six balls where 3 combinations of black and white balls are present.

```
X is black ball
0 is while ball
```

They are placed like `X0X0X0` and there are 4 blanks available before these six balls.
So final input placement is below

```
_ _ _ _ X 0 X 0 X 0
```

The question was to move balls in pairs of two adjacent balls, so that white balls end on left and balck on right using three steps only.

I did below

```
_ _ 0 X X _ _ 0 X 0
_ _ 0 X X X 0 0 _ _
0 0 0 X X X
```

It was one answer which was correct, but two answers was required. I couldnt think of second.

Any help ? It was required to write in java.

Comment: _move balls in pairs of two adjacent balls_ you means 2 adjacent means only 2 balls right ? but  your solution use 3 !

Comment: @Eklavya, first I moved position 6 & 7 to 3 & 4, then 9 & 10 to 6 & 7 and at last 7 & 8 to 1 & 0

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but anyways, here's an answer that is most likely also along the lines of what your company wanted to see (except for the fact that I used python):

```
from collections import deque as deq

def solve_rec():
    visited = set()
    q = deq()
    q.append(('----X0X0X0', 0, []))
    
    while q:
        s, c, p = q.popleft()
        print(s, c, p)
        if s in visited:
            continue
        if c == 3:
            continue

        visited.add(s)
        
        for n in gen_steps(s):
            q.append((n, c + 1, p + [s]))
        
    

def gen_steps(state):
    state = list(state)
    filled_pairs = [i for i in range(len(state) - 1) if state[i] != '-' and state[i + 1] != '-']
    for i in filled_pairs:
        tmp = state[:]
        tmp[i:i + 2] = '--'
        empty_pairs = [j for j in range(len(state) - 1) if tmp[j] == '-' and tmp[j + 1] == '-' and j != i]
        for j in empty_pairs:
            tmp[j:j + 2] = state[i:i + 2]
            yield ''.join(tmp)
            tmp[j:j + 2] = '--'

solve_rec()
```

Filtering the output with the regex `^-*(X-*){3}-*(0-*){3}-*` we get two solutions:

```
000XXX---- 3 ['----X0X0X0', '--0XX--0X0', '--0XXX00--']
000X--XX-- 3 ['----X0X0X0', '--0XX0X--0', '--0X--XX00']
```

These are the only possible states reachable within three steps, so [@Andis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161516/4668606) is correct. The algorithm used in the code is [Breadth-First-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 1):

if gaps are allowed, you can move 8&9 to 3&4, 5&6 to 8&9 and then 9&10 to 1&2.

```
_ _ _ _ X 0 X 0 X 0
_ _ 0 X X 0 X _ _ 0
_ _ 0 X _ _ X X 0 0
0 0 0 X _ _ X X _ _
```

Comment: There was no stipulation on gaps so it looks good to me.

Comment: If there is no stipulation on gaps there are more than two solutions. But the OP says *but two answers was required* which I m not sure if it meant that the balls have to be together in the final placement.

Comment: @SomeDude, there is stipulation on gap. sorry fogot to add in question